# PHP Reduce number of sql query

Tags: php, sql

I've two tables:

CATEGORY

```
Id  Name  Thumbnail
```

ARTICLE

```
Id  Title  Content  CategoryId  CreatedOn
```

How can I select the last `Article` of each `Category` without using a nested query?

Comment: What have you tried? What database are you using? This doesn't sound like a PHP question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Join:

```
SELECT ARTICLE.ID, TITLE, CONTENT, CATEGORYID, MAX(CREATEDON)
  FROM ARTICLE
       INNER JOIN CATEGORY
               ON CATEGORY.ID = ARTICLE.CATEGORYID
GROUP BY ARTICLE.ID, TITLE, CONTENT, CATEGORYID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*
from article a
where a.createdon = (select max(a2.createdon)
                     from article a2
                     where a2.CategoryId = a.CategoryId
                    );
```

There are other methods, but this has good performance across most databases if you have an index on `article(CategoryId, createdon)`.